# How to wire F4-FC-t-motor to FrSky-Xr602t-f2-D16 receiver

Tags: transmitter, wiring, frsky-xm+, f4

I have a [t-motor F4 flight controller](https://droneshop.nl/t-motor-f4-hd-flight-controller) which I want to wire to a crossover [Frsky D16-XR602T-F2 receiver](https://www.crossover-rx.com/productinfo/302368.html). For power (5v) and ground, it is clear and it works. I connected the `S BUS` on the receiver to `R3 UART` on my FC but it doesn't connect to my transmitter (Jumper T12). I follow all the steps on the quick start guide. So in CLI settings, I set: `serialrx halfduplex = ON` and `serialrx inverted = OFF`.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you having trouble binding the receiver to the transmitter or wiring the receiver to the flight controller?

Comment: Well kinda both. If wiring goes wrong you can't bind neither, right?

Comment: no, generally as long as the receiver has power (which it seems it does have), you should be able to bind it.

Comment: @DronesandWhatnot Good to know, thanks. Let's first deal with the wiring. I am not sure the problem is binding or wiring, but when I use the controls on the transmitter, it doesn't rotate the motors.

Comment: have you set an arm switch? Without it the motors won’t spin. The best way to see if the receiver is getting info to the FC is to go to the receiver tab in Betaflight and see if it is registering any input when you move the sticks on the radio. You may need the drone plugged in depending on how your receiver is hooked up.